# Use the running rails application instance in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

As we all know, when some rake task is started, the following steps happen:

1. Rails loads(new `Rails::Application` instance initializes)
2. Then rake task run

So, rails app instances will be different for rake task and for rails server.
I wonder, is it possible to share rails server instance with rake tasks or rails console? 
This could be workaround in case if I want a rake task, that modifies class variable, or class instance variable in running rails server application.

In my running application, I have a model with a class instance variable

```
class User
  @some_flag = false

  class << self
    def some_flag
      @some_flag
    end

    def some_flag=(val)
      @some_flag = val
    end
  end
end
```

in my rake task, that is scheduled to run in background I want to update that variable:

```
namespace :user do
  desc "update flag"
  task update: :environment do
    User.some_flag = ENV['flag']
  end
end
```

and then to use updated value in application

Comment: can you elaborate with example as to what and why exactly you want to do, it might have a solution in the different direction unlike you looking for.

Comment: If you want to do that, I think it's better to use environment variables or to persist these flags on the database.

Comment: Yep, I guess it is impossible, better to use database

Answer (score 0):

There was a small hack which I had used when I wanted to update `constants` through `Model` which might be helpful here.

Create a `constants.rb` file inside `initializers` folder of the app:

```
class Constant
  SOME_FLAG = false
end
```

When you want to update the flag through rake task, you can:

```
task update: :environment do
  Constant.const_set('SOME_FLAG', ENV['flag'])
end
```

Hope it helps..